# How do I ascertain correct user for exim log error?

Tags: centos, permissions, exim

Am I correct in thinking that this line

```
2014-05-28 13:22:50 failed to open /etc/backupmxhosts for linear search: Permission denied (euid=47 egid=12)
```

is telling me that the user that is trying to open this file (and failing) is the user with ID of 47 and is a member of group 12?

If this is true, in order to fix the mucked up permissions, can I look in **/etc/passwd** and find which user:group these refer to, and chown the file back to them?

Comment: Yes. `euid` and `egid` refer to the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` correspondingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the exim mail server process is running as user 47 and group 12 (probably exim:mail).  It's trying to read the file /etc/backupmxhosts as part of its delivery process, but the permissions of that file are such that the user:group (exim:mail) cannot read it, or it could be a symlink to a non-existent file.  Fix your ownership and/or permissions of that file.